# How to set ansible configuration variables run time

Tags: ansible

I need to set some ansible configuration variables during execution within the playbook. I tried following, but its not working:

```
--> cat site.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        log_path: "/home/monk/test/ansible_set_run_time"

- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    log_path: "{{ log_path }}"
  tasks:
    - shell: "echo $log_path"
      register: res

    - debug:
        msg: "log_path = {{ res.stdout }}"
```

`ansible.cfg` content at the current directory:

```
-->cat /home/monk/test/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
log_path = /home/monk/test/ansiblelog_from_cfg
```

This always generate the log file set by `/home/monk/test/ansible.cfg` and never by the `log_path` set within the playbook.

Why I do not want to use `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` ,`$PWD/ansible.cfg` , or `$HOME/.ansible.cfg` ?

Reason: I will be running this on remote node, where there is a `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file already present which contains the global settings which I cannot change , At the same time I cannot use `$PWD/ansible.cfg` because, I also need the content of `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`.

So TLDR, I need to read the contents of `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` and local `ansible.cfg` and use them both . I can merge them all but I cannot control the changes of `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` so my merged changes may be outdated. This is why I want to define my configuration variable stored within the playbooks and I will keep reading `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`.

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.5.2
  config file = /home/monk/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/monk/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

I can see that `set_fact` is showing the desired value, but `log_path` is not coming into the effect for the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook  -i data.ini  playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [set_fact] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [command] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "log_path = /home/monk/test/ansible_set_run_time"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: What version of Ansible are you currently running? `ansible --version` And just to confirm, when you run the example above, the debug message is returning "log_path = /home/monk/test/ansiblelog_from_cfg" rather than the set_fact log path?

Comment: @markybb41 : see the update, it does return the desired log_path in the print out , but the `log_path` is not coming into effect for further playbook execution

Comment: The problem with what you are doing is that by the time your playbook is run ansible has already read the log file path, now you expect to change a run-time config of ansible?

Comment: `log_path` is just one example, is there a way to change `roles_path` or any other params on run time ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried, setting the variables in one playbook and calling it through another, but it does not help.

Comment: @monk, Its not about playbook. Playbook is being run by `ansible` the tool, and your trying to change to log of the tool itself from with in a playbook. Even before any playbook is loaded the log config most probably is already loaded

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly? If you want a single task to be logged to specific file, there are other ways of doing that. It's bad practice to change such thing at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Try below. You can set using shell environment variable.

```
export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH="/home/monk/test/ansible_set_run_time"
ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

Comment: Thanks , I was aware of this option see(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691804/how-to-set-ansible-config-variables-from-user-defined-ansible-cfg). I appreciate this help. But I am trying to do this withing the playbook.

Comment: Assuming you are able to change the log path in task n, where will the logs till that task will be logged. So it must be defined before the play starts running either through ansible.cfg or environment variable or some parameter to the ansible-playbook command.

Comment: so are you suggesting there is NO way to change these configuration variables run time ?

Comment: Yes, it can't be changed when the playbook is running, is my understandings.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a run time modification of the configuration variable but this can help with the gist of your requirement. You may read all the configuration files and concatenate them into `$PWD/ansible.cfg`.

This is the precedence of ansible.cfg files read by ansible:

```
ANSIBLE_CONFIG (environment variable if set)
ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
~/.ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

So you need to start reading starting in following sequence , so that you can preserve the precedence :

```
/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
~/.ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
ANSIBLE_CONFIG (environment variable if set)
```

What this will do:

This will preserve your configuration at the same time preserving the configuration of other ansible.cfg files. Of course this will overwrite the overlapping variables between the files keeping priority to the last file.

As of ansible 2.6 this is only known solution.  Note that, the later the variable in the concatenated file , it will overwrite the previous occurrence of same variable.